# python+json<=(list as json object)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

```
with open ("xyz.json") as f:
    json_load=json.load(f)
    lis=["response.result.Potentials","response.result.Potentials.row",...........]
```

How to pass from list `l1` to JSON object (getting the variable from list `l1` and passing the variables JSON object).(IF we add anything to list and calls it should print json values).

```
print(data[l1[0]])
```

i want print from list `l1` i.e `print(data[response][result][Potentials])`

```
print(data[l1[1]])
```

i.e `print(data[response][result][Potentials][row])` in JSON format:

```
 {"response":
        {"result":
            {"Potentials":
                {"row":
                    [
                    {"no":"1","FL":
                        {"content":"523836000004148171","val":"POTENTIALID"}
                    },
                    {"no":"2","FL":
                        {"content":"523836000004924051","val":"POTENTIALID"}
                    },
                    {"no":"3","FL":
                        [
                        {"content":"523836000005318448","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                        {"content":"694275295","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"no":"4","FL":
                        [
                        {"content":"523836000005318662","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                        {"content":"729545274","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"no":"5","FL":
                        [
                        {"content":"523836000005318663","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                        {"content":"903187021","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {"no":"6","FL":
                        {"content":"523836000005322387","val":"POTENTIALID"}
                    },
                    {"no":"7","FL":
                        [
                        {"content":"523836000005332558","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                        {"content":"729416761","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                }
            },
        "uri":"/crm/private/json/Potentials/getSearchRecords"}
    }
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the real question is: "How can I translate the string `"a.b.c"` into a lookup in a dictionary `d` as `d[a][b][c]`" ?

Comment: Your list contains dictionary keys separated by `.` characters. Split each key by `.` (lis[0].split('.')`, and use the techniques in the dupe to traverse your dictionaries and retrieve each value: `getFromDict(json_load, lis[0].split('.'))`